# How can I fix my function?

Tags: python, function

I am being told.. from comments to fix my function to make it look "cleaner". I've tried alot.. but i don't know how to use llambda to accomplish what I'm trying to do. My code works.. it just isn't what is being asked of me.

Here is my code with suggestions on how to fix it.

```
def immutable_fibonacci(position):

    #define a lambda instead of def here
    def compute_fib (previousSeries, ignore):
        newList = previousSeries

        if len(newList) < 2: # Do this outside and keep this function focused only on returning a new list with last element being sum of previous two elements
           newList.append(1)

        else:
           first = newList[-1]
           second = newList[-2]
           newList.append(first+second)
        return newList

    range=[None]*position
    return reduce(compute_fib, range, []) 

#Above is too much code. How about something like this:
#next_series = lambda series,_ : (Use these instead of the above line)
#return reduce(next_series, range(position - 2), [1, 1])
```

Anything helps.. I am just confused on how I can implement these suggestions.

Here is what I attempted.

```
def immutable_fibonacci(position):
    range=[None]*position
    next_series = lambda series, _ : series.append(series[-1] + series[-2])
    return reduce(next_series, range(position - 2), [1, 1])
```

Comment: In general it's probably not a good idea to redefine `range`.

Comment: What's immutable referring to?

Comment: The whole design of that code is crazy. Why use `reduce` with a list of `None` values instead of a simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

The `append` function returns None. You need to return a renewed array

```
next_series = lambda series: series + [series[-1] + series[-2]]
```

Also renaming `range` isn't serving any purpose.

```
def immutable_fibonacci(position):
    next_series = lambda series: series + [series[-1] + series[-2]]
    return reduce(next_series, range(position - 2), [1, 1])
```

This is assuming you only call the function for positions >= 2. Conventionally fib(0) is 0 and fib(1) is 1.

Comment: that still doesnt work... although it makes more sense than what I did. I get an error that list object is not callable in line 3

Comment: Does it need to compute a fibonacci sequence of length 0 or 1?

Comment: basically the position i will send is 6. it should compute 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8